# jQuery .when.apply().done(function(){ }) - does trigger on always refresh from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, bing-maps

I am loading maps in **bing v8 apis** and need to read the address. The code works well in Edge/Chrome/IE11.

In IE11, if I open a clean browser, the map shows the correct info, but after that it shows only map center. 
It works only again if I clear cached files (specially JS files) or I am running in debug mode and using always refresh from server.

The code specifically has issue is:

```
$.when.apply($, waitHandles).done(function () {
    var mapData = ensureMapInitialized();
    var map = mapData.Map;
});
```

Comment: Not certain what issue is?

Comment: `$.when.apply($, waitHandles).done` has nothing to do with an old broken web browsers broken handling of cache :p